# Choose an element in a list and pass it in a controller

Tags: angularjs, rest, jhipster

I am working on a JHispter project with an AngularJS front-end and a Java back-end with a mongodb database.

In the front, I did a code in order to choose an id from a list and pass it to the controller in order to make the controller to  take into account the id and call a REST API request.

**code-budget.html**

Here, the code of the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="listCodeBudget"> Choose a budget code: </label><br>
        <select name="codeBudget" ng-change="vm.updateBudget()" ng-model="vm.idcode">
            <option value="P24DRR000">Support, Realisation and Maintenance</option>
            <option value="P24DRPIL00">Piloting DSI structure</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <nvd3 options='vm.optionsBudget' data='vm.dataResume'></nvd3>
</div>
```

**code-budget.controller.js**

Here, the controller where I did a method vm.update which is binded with the HTML code. I am using the Angular-nvd3 library in order to create charts. The code for the creation of the chart is not very important so I did not put all the code. The thing which is important here is vm.idcode which I pass through the aggregateByCodeBudget method which has his equivalent in the Java back-end in order to retrieve the information according to the vm.idcode (the budget code id).

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('dashboardApp')
        .controller('CodeBudgetController', CodeBudgetController);

    CodeBudgetController.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams', 'DataUtils', 'ClarityResourceAffectation'];

    function CodeBudgetController ($timeout, $scope, $stateParams, DataUtils, ClarityResourceAffectation) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.byteSize = DataUtils.byteSize;
        vm.openFile = DataUtils.openFile;

        $timeout(function (){
            angular.element('.form-group:eq(1)>input').focus();
        });

        vm.updateBudget = function()
        {
            ClarityResourceAffectation.aggregateByCodeBudget(vm.idcode, function(readings) {
                    alert(vm.idcode);
                var dataBudget;
                dataBudget = [];

                readings.forEach(function (item) {
                    dataBudget.push({
                        //some code
                    });
                });

                vm.optionsBudget = {
                    //some code
                };

                vm.dataBudget = [{
                    //some code
                }];
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

**clarity-resource-affectation.state.js**

The state.js file where I put the HTML file, the controller and the controller as notation:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('dashboardApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
.state('code-budget', {
        parent: 'entity',
            url: '/code-budget',
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                pageTitle: 'dashboardApp.clarityResourceAffectation.home.title'
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/code-budget.html',
                    controller: 'CodeBudgetController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate,$translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('clarityResourceAffectation');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

**clarity-resource-affectation.service.js**

The service.js file here. I am working on this method 'aggregateByCodeBudget'. You can find the url fiel which allows to do the mapping with the Java back-end code.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('dashboardApp')
        .factory('ClarityResourceAffectation', ClarityResourceAffectation);

    ClarityResourceAffectation.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function ClarityResourceAffectation ($resource) {
        var resourceUrl =  'clarity/' + 'api/clarity-resource-affectations/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'aggregateByCodeBudget': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                url: 'clarity/api/clarity-resource-affectations/ligne-budgetaire/:idcode'
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Actually, when I put an alert(vm.idcode) in the controller, it appears correctly but it is not taken into account in the function aggregateByCodeBudget as a parameter.

Can you tell me if something in which I did is wrong? Can I put the parameter vm.idcode just before the "function(readings)" parameter?

Perhaps, there is another way to do that.

I add the methods of the Java back-end in order to make you to have a better understanding of the problem. I simplified a little the java back-end classes in order to put just the necessary concerning the problem.

**The repository layer:**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationRepositoryImpl implements ClarityResourceAffectationRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
        public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateByCodeBudget(String codeBudget) {
            Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("codeBudgetaireProjet").is(codeBudget).and("mois").ne(null).and("annee").is(2017)),
                    group("mois", "annee").sum("consoJh").as("totalConsoJh").sum("rafJh").as("totalRafJh"),
                    sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(), "annee", "mois"));

            AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, ClarityResourceAffectation.class,
                    ClarityResourceAffectationReport.class);
            List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> clarityResourceAffectationReports = groupResults.getMappedResults();

            return clarityResourceAffectationReports;
        }
}
```

**The service layer:**

```
@Service
public class ClarityResourceAffectationServiceImpl implements ClarityResourceAffectationService{
    @Override
        public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateByCodeBudget(String codeBudget) {
            log.debug("Request to aggregateByCodeBudget : {}", codeBudget);
            List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> result = clarityResourceAffectationRepository
                    .aggregateByCodeBudget(codeBudget);

            return result;
        }
}
```

**The REST layer:**
In this class, you can find the mapping with the AngularJS part with the @GetMapping annotation.

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing ClarityResourceAffectation.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ClarityResourceAffectationResource {
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ClarityResourceAffectationResource {
    @GetMapping("/clarity-resource-affectations/ligne-budgetaire/{idcode}")
        @Timed
        public ResponseEntity<List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport>> aggregateByCodeBudget(@PathVariable String idcode) {
            log.debug("REST request to get aggregateByCodeBudget : {}", idcode);
            List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> result = clarityResourceAffectationService.aggregateByCodeBudget(idcode);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `aggregateByCodeBudget`? I don't see it in `ClarityResourceAffectation`.

Comment: @Frank Modica I put now all the java back-end code. Actually, the implementation of the aggregateByCodeBudget is in the **ClarityResourceAffectationRepositoryImpl** java class. And in the AngularJS **clarity-resource-affectation.service.js**, I updated the name of the method which was **aggregateByLigneBudgetaire** before and now it is the same as it is in the Java back-end: **aggregateByCodeBudget**. Actually, the name is not important here, it is the URL mapping between the AngularJS part and the Java back-end part which is important.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I was looking for the aggregateByCodeBudget JavaScript implementation, to see what it does with your parameters. But I didn't understand how $resource works, so now I see that it is defined as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with `$resource`, but the examples I see usually pass an object with the parameter name as a property. Something like this:

```
ClarityResourceAffectation.aggregateByCodeBudget({ id: vm.idcode }, function() { ... });
```

In your case you may want to change your `$resource` code to just use `:id`, since I see both `:id` and `:idcode` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, it works. Actually in my code, I just replaced `vm.idcode` by `{idcode: vm.idcode}`. You must just be careful to put the good id in the **clarity-resource-affectation.service.js** file in the URL for the mapping. Here, the URL must be finished by `:idcode`.

Comment: It is ok, when I said: "You must...", I was talking in general not because you did not put `idcode`. I understood the explanation and I adaptated my code. It is just for the others who may have the same problem.